# Execute when an application is destroyed/ undeployed

Tags: java

I have a static initialization block where I read data from DB into certain variables, update that data during the lifetime of the application & save it to DB at regular periodic intervals but when the application is unexpectedly/suddently destroyed/ undeployed I want to write back the current state of the variable back to the DB.

How can I implement this with on destroy trigger in Java ?

---

## Edit:

What about the `@PreDestroy` annotation, could it be useful for my case ?

Comment: anyone knows if the `finalize()` method would be useful for this purpose ? pros/cons ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a web application, you can implement and register a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). Its `contextInitialized` method will be called once upon deployment, and `contextDestroyed` will be called once on undeployment.

However if the container is ungracefully terminated, `contextDestroyed` still may not have a chance to run.

See [this page](http://www.javabeat.net/examples/2009/02/26/servletcontextlistener-example/) for an example of setting one up.

Comment: Yes this is a webapp but since I was doing initization/intial read within a static initization block in a class, I was wondering it would be nice if I could trigger ondestroy within the same class, if possible ?!

Comment: Running startup/shutdown logic based on class loading/unloading seems much less predictable. It's possible you could hook into the class being unloaded but I'm not the one to ask about this.